# Query string properties stored as XML

Tags: c#, sql, xml, entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity Framework to query a db which is defined by a model: inside this model I have several classes having a `#region dynamic values`:

```
[DataContract]
public class Job : AbstractEntity, IJob
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    ...

    #region dynamic values

    [DataMember]
    public virtual string MetadataValue { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string ParametersValue { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string AttributesValue { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region links
    ...
    #endregion
}
```

`AttributesValue`, `MetadataValue` and `ParametersValue` are declared as string but are stored inside the db as XML documents. I am aware that this is not consistent with the model and should be changed, but for some reasons it has been managed this way and I am not allowed to modify it. 
I have created a Unit Test in order to better handle the problem, and here is the code:

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    private ModelContext mc;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInit()
    {
        IModelContextFactory mfactory = ModelContextFactory.GetFactory();
        mc = mfactory.CreateContextWithoutClientId();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        DbSet<Job> jobs = mc.Job;

        IQueryable<string> query = jobs
            .Where(elem => elem.AttributesValue == "<coll><item><key>ids:ui:description</key><value>Session Test</value></item><item><key>ids:all:type</key><value>signature</value></item></coll>")
            .Select(elem => elem.AttributesValue);

        List<string> attrs = new List<string>(query);
        foreach (string av in attrs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(av ?? "null");
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
    }
}
```

A quick explanation about the `TestInit` and `ModelContext`:
`ModelContext` inherit from `DbContext` and is an abstract class implemented by `SqlModelContext` and `OracleModelContext` (both override `OnModelCreating`). Depending on the connection string, `CreateContextWithoutClientId` return a `SqlModelContext` or an `OracleModelContext`. Summary: a Factory pattern.

Let's get down to brass tacks: the `TestMethod1`. 
The problem here is in the `Where` method and the error returned is, as expected:

> SqlException: The data types nvarchar and xml are incompatible in the equal to operator.

(From now on I will only consider the `AttributesValue` property)

I thought of some possible solutions, which are:

- Creating a new property inside the model (but not mapped to the db) and use it as a "proxy" instead of accessing directly `AttributesValue`. However only mapped  properties can be used in Linq, so I discarded it.
- Operating directly on the inner SQL query generated by the `IQueryable` and using a customized `CAST` for Oracle and Sql Server db. I'd rather avoid go for this for obvious reasons.

Is there a way to specify a custom Property Getter so that I can cast `AttributesValue` to string before it is accessed? Or maybe some configuration on the `DbModelBuilder`?

I'm using standard Entity Framework 6, Code-First approach.

Comment: How could it help me? However, it does not work, just tried. Thanks anyway.

Comment: EF6 or EF Core? If EF6, code first model or edmx?

Comment: @IvanStoev I completely forgot to specify it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard xml data type or standard canonical function for converting string to xml or vice versa.

Fortunately EF6 supports the so called [Entity SQL Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/entity-sql-language) which supports an useful construct called [CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/cast-entity-sql):

```
CAST (expression AS data_type)
```

> The cast expression has similar semantics to the Transact-SQL CONVERT expression. The cast expression is used to convert a value of one type into a value of another type.

It can be utilized with the help of the [EntityFramework.Functions](https://github.com/Dixin/EntityFramework.Functions) package and [Model defined functions](https://weblogs.asp.net/Dixin/EntityFramework.Functions#Model_defined_function).

Model defined functions allow you to associate Entity SQL expression with user defined function. The requirement is that the function argument must be an entity.

The good thing about Entity SQL operators is that they are database independent (similar to canonical functions), so the final SQL is still generated by the database provider, hence you don't need to write separate implementations for SqlServer and Oracle.

Install the EntityFramework.Functions package through [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Functions) and add the following class (note: all the code requires `using EntityFramework.Functions;`):

```
public static class JobFunctions
{
    const string Namespace = "EFTest";

    [ModelDefinedFunction(nameof(MetadataValueXml), Namespace, "'' + CAST(Job.MetadataValue AS String)")]
    public static string MetadataValueXml(this Job job) => job.MetadataValue;

    [ModelDefinedFunction(nameof(ParametersValueXml), Namespace, "'' + CAST(Job.ParametersValue AS String)")]
    public static string ParametersValueXml(this Job job) => job.ParametersValue;

    [ModelDefinedFunction(nameof(AttributesValueXml), Namespace, "'' + CAST(Job.AttributesValue AS String)")]
    public static string AttributesValueXml(this Job job) => job.AttributesValue;
}
```

Basically we add simple extension method for each xml property. The body of the methods doesn't do something useful - the whole purpose of these methods is not to be called directly, but to be translated to SQL when used inside LINQ to Entities query. The required mapping is provided through `ModelDefinedFunctionAttribute` and applied via package implemented custom [`FunctionConvention`](https://weblogs.asp.net/Dixin/EntityFramework.Functions#FunctionConvention_and_FunctionConvention<TFunctions>). The `Namespace` constant must be equal to `typeof(Job).Namespace`. Unfortunately due to the requirement that attributes can use only constants, we can't avoid that hardcoded string as well as the entity class / property names inside the Entity SQL string.

One thing that needs more explanation is the usage of `'' + CAST`. I wish we could use simply `CAST`, but my tests show that SqlServer is "too smart" (or buggy?) and removes the `CAST` from expression when used inside `WHERE`. The trick with appending the empty string prevents that behavior.

Then you need to add these functions to entity model by adding the following line to your db context `OnModelCreating` override:

```
modelBuilder.AddFunctions(typeof(JobFunctions));
```

Now you can use them inside your LINQ to Entities query:

```
IQueryable<string> query = jobs
    .Where(elem => elem.AttributesValueXml() == "<coll><item><key>ids:ui:description</key><value>Session Test</value></item><item><key>ids:all:type</key><value>signature</value></item></coll>")
    .Select(elem => elem.AttributesValue);
```

which translates to something like this in SqlServer:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[AttributesValue] AS [AttributesValue]
    FROM [dbo].[Jobs] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE N'<coll><item><key>ids:ui:description</key><value>Session Test</value></item><item><key>ids:all:type</key><value>signature</value></item></coll>'
    = ('' +  CAST( [Extent1].[AttributesValue] AS nvarchar(max)))
```

and in Oracle:

```
SELECT
"Extent1"."AttributesValue" AS "AttributesValue"
FROM "ORATST"."Jobs" "Extent1"
WHERE ('<coll><item><key>ids:ui:description</key><value>Session Test</value></item><item><key>ids:all:type</key><value>signature</value></item></coll>'
= ((('')||(TO_NCLOB("Extent1"."AttributesValue")))))
```

Comment: Right this morning I found out about the existence of `EntityFramework.Function package`. However, really good explanation. If it works, tomorrow I am going to accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Nice piece of work Ivan! One caveat though. As you know, with the XML datatype the preferred way of querying is to use the database's built-in XPath query operators. Of course, there is no support for those operators in EF, so from a performance POV it may be better to run SQL statements with, for example, Dapper. I don't consider that an answer to this question though, as yours is.

Comment: It works perfectly. Only one thing seems pretty weird: the namespace I have to use is *CodeFirstNamespace* even though there is not even a match of it inside my solution.

Comment: Yeah, that's strange. And I cannot use that, `Function` code throws exception that I should use "EFTest" in my case. Looking at the package source code, it validates the namespace against the namespace of the first entity type in the conceptual model. "CodeFirstNamespace" sounds like there is an entity automatically generated by EF, but I have no idea how and when.